# $e^\pi - \pi^e < 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, exponentiation, pi

We have [Comparing $\pi^e$ and $e^\pi$ without calculating them](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/7892/6400) but it doesn't give an approximation of the actual difference. Is there a way without calcualting an approximation of them to prove $e^\pi - \pi^e < 1$  ?

Comment: We can still follow some of the proofs there to conclude $e^{\pi}<1+\pi^e$. Did you try this?

Comment: Could you link the one that works for this? I must have missed something obvious.

Comment: The difference is small, the task won't be easy.

Comment: Like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1410230/proving-that-e-pi-pie-lt-1-without-using-a-calculator)?

Answer (score 0):

**If that can help:**

Let $f(x):=e^x-x^e$. This function has a minimum at $x=e$ (double root), and the second order Taylor development is

$$y\approx g(x):=e^{e-1}(x-e)^2.$$

This approximation exceeds $f$, but we still have $g(\pi)<1$.

In blue, $f$, in black, $g$.

[image]

Comment: Hard to see definitely that the black curve is less than $1$ at $x=\pi$ from this plot.

Comment: Oh, you want the blue plot less than 1.  That is pretty clear, but then you wouldn't need the Taylor series.